# how to take a response in ajax from nodejs

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax

I am trying submit a form and after that it send a status `success` via AJAX.
But when I'm sending a status from NodeJS after submitting the form it does not reach the AJAX code, as I have put an `alert()` statement to check if it reaches it. The alert is not triggered, but it directly prints that value which I wrote in `send('this text is printed')`.

My test.js file is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#form_submit').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/submitForm',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function(result) {
                alert(result.status);
                if (result.status === "success") {
                    alert("success");
                    window.location = '/nextPage';

                } else {
                    alert("failure");
                }

            },
            error: function(err) {
                alert('error');
            }
        })
    });
});
```

and my NodeJS code is given below

```
app.post('/submitForm', function(req, res) {
    // submitted form to database
    var form = new Form({
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        number: req.body.number,
    });
    form.save(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            throw new Error(err);
        } else {
            res.send({
                status: 'success',
                message: 'successfully form created'
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `there is no alert in ajax but directly print that send('') value` - Can you clarify what this means? I couldn't understand what is the problem.

Comment: @Hamsterrific means i specify `alert(result.status);` in my ajax code but it does'nt occur instead  of `res.send({ 'this is printed in next page' }) ;` this occer

Answer (score -1):

You have to change res.send() to res.json() in order to be able to send JSON data.

Comment: still there is no response in ajax.

Comment: This should've been a comment