# how to take a request in ajax from nodejs

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax

i ask this question previous [how to take a response in ajax from nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48479788/how-to-take-a-response-in-ajax-from-nodejs/48480078#48480078) but no answer that.

Please someone help me in this

Comment: if you have any answer then tell me.

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, it doesn't matter if server is nodejs or php, if it gives a response in postman then you can fetch and decode (if json) using js? If your server endpoint works and sends a response after a request. For that, I will suggest using postman https://www.getpostman.com/

Comment: json is printed `{
    "status": "success",
    "message": "successfully form created"
}`  but it have to send the status in ajax.

Comment: I just didn't get you? you just need status ?? then perse that printed node. check this link https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp